# crontab used for controller to save data in symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

```
namespace ApiMaps\ApiMapBundle\Controller;

       class GetApiController extends Controller {
              public function getapiAction() {
                     ----gettting data from api 
                     ----save it in data base 
            return new Response();
```

I want to run this controller periodically from Centos (server) with the helps of crontab what steps i need to do for this..any idea?

Comment: Move the process from your controller to a command (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html). Then call the command in your crontab like `0 * * * * /path/to/your/deployment/app/console --env=prod your:command:name`.

Comment: thanks for your answer..

Comment: one question that how can i use the doctrain commonds which is specifically used the controller. query builder etc can i use these commond in this console?

Comment: A controller is essentially just a service that is called by the router. A console command can do all of the same things, except for have access to the current request path/host/etc as their isn't one.